# django - q object filtering getlist

Tags: python, django, django-filter, query-string

I want to make an intersection by bringing intelligence,strength, and charm from the stat variable to the getlist, but it only comes out as a combination. What could be the reason? I'm waiting for your help.

```
class ProductListView(View):
def get(self,request):
    category     = request.GET.get('category', None)
    sub_category = request.GET.get('sub_category', None)
    stat         = request.GET.getlist('stat', None)

    q=Q()

    if category:
        q &=Q(sub_category__category__name=category)

    if sub_category:
        q &=Q(sub_category__name=sub_category)
    
    if stat:
        q &=Q(coursestat__stat__name__in=stat)

    
    products = Course.objects.filter(q).distinct()
    
    results=[{  "course_id"      : product.id,
                "thumbnail"      : product.thumbnail_image_url,
                "user_name"      : product.user.name,
                "sub_category"   : product.sub_category.name,
                "course_name"    : product.name,
                "price"          : product.price,
                "payment_period" : product.payment_period,
                "course_like"    : product.like_set.count()
                } for product in products]
        
    return JsonResponse({"results" : results})
```

The query parameters created by Postman are as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXkhY.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "only comes out as a combination"?  It might also help if you posted the parts of the models that you are querying. Especially the relationships (ForeignKey, ManyToMany, etc.)

Comment: Did you mean you get matches when stat=='intelligence' OR stat=='strength'  as well as both? Because that's what __in=stat is supposed to do. A match on anything in the stat list.